# Any generalization of the complex conjugates in the theory of fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, field-theory

We know that for any complex number $z = x + \iota y$, where $x$ and $y$ are *real numbers*, there exists the  complex number $\overline{z} = x - \iota y$, and the complex numbers $z$ and $\overline{z}$ are said to be the *complex conjugates* of each other.

Of course, every real number is its own conjugate.

Now is there any generalization of this notion of conjugate pairs to elements of a general abstract field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complex numbers are an extension of the real numbers, and complex conjugation is a field automorphism of the complex numbers fixing the reals.

In general, if $F$ is a field and $E$ is an extension of $F$ (that is, a field containing $F$), then one can speak of the automorphisms of $E$ that fix the elements of $F$. That's the idea analogous to complex conjugate. It's a really, really important concept. It forms the basis of Galois Theory, for one thing.

Comment: As an example, let $F$ be the rationals, and let $E$ be the smallest field containing $F$ and $\sqrt2$; $E$ turns out to be all the numbers $a+b\sqrt2$, with $a,b$ rational. Then $a+b\sqrt2$ and $a-b\sqrt2$ are conjugate.

Comment: let $E$ and $F$ be arbitrary fields such that $E$ is an extension of $F$. Can we explictly construct an automorphism of $E$ that fixes the elements of $F$? Of course, this is the identity automorphism when $E = F$. But what if $F \subsetneq  E$? Can you please include the details toward the end of your answer?

Comment: The details would fill a book, Saaqib. Sometimes, the identity automorphism is the only one, e.g., when $F$ is the rationals, and $E$ is the smallest field containing $F$ and $\root3\of2$. An important set of examples arise from $E$ being the smallest field containing $F$ and $\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is a root of some polynomial $f$ with coefficients in $F$ and irreducible over $F$. Then every element of $E$ is a polynomial in $\alpha$ with coefficients in $F$, and you can use that to construct, for every root $\beta$ of $f$ in $E$, an automorphism that takes $\alpha$ to $\beta$. (continued)

Comment: (continued) But as I say, whole books have been written about this circle of ideas. Look for Field Theory and Galois Theory, or chapters about these concepts in introductory Abstract Algebra texts.

Comment: So, are you satisfied with my answer, Saaqib?

Comment: Are you still here, Saaqib?

Comment: yes, I am. Thank you so much!